# cloudformation template to create IAM role with inline policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an IAM role using the below template. I am able to create the role with  managed policies. When I try to add inline policy in my template I get the error

"Property PolicyDocument cannot be empty."

```
{
"Resources": {
"test": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole",
        ],
      "Policies": [
      "PolicyName" : "create_snapshot",
      "PolicyDocument" : {
         "Version" : "2012-10-17",
         "Statement": [ {
         "Effect"   : "Allow",
         "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot"
            ],
         "Resource" : "*"
         } ]      
      }
],
"RoleName": "test"
      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try: "Policies": [ { "PolicyName" : "create_snapshot" , ... } ]

Comment: after adding the {} it works. thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Policies is a list of policy objects which is written as follows in JSON, with each individual policy object embedded in curly braces inside the [] list:

```
"Policies": [
  {
    "PolicyName" : "policy01",
    "PolicyDocument" : { "abc": "xyz" }
  },
  {
    "PolicyName" : "policy02",
    "PolicyDocument" : { "abc": "xyz" }
  }
]
```

Or as follows in YAML:

```
Policies:
- PolicyName: policy01
  PolicyDocument:
    abc: xyz
- PolicyName: policy02
  PolicyDocument:
    abc: xyz
```